# What game uses dice with compass point arrows, forbidden signs, explosions, arrows and targeting reticles?

Tags: identify-this-game, dice

A while ago I bought a few bags of factory 2nd dice. Out of those bags, there are a handful of dice that I have not been able to immediately identify. Some I have later been able to identify through image searching, such as the Warhammer Blood Angels, Adeptus Mechanicus and Tyranids logo dice, as well as the green and pink nebular swirl dice.

However, I am still unsure as to what some of the dice are. I’ve tried looking at dice websites, searching on Google and even using reverse image searches, all to no avail. For some, I am not even sure how to concisely describe them to accurately search for them.

What I want to know is what game are these dice from? Or, if they are not from a specific game, what they are called. Below are images of the dice:

[image]

I also have green and purple dice similar to the ones in the above image.

[This question has also been asked over at  RPG.SE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149747/what-game-uses-dice-with-compass-point-arrows-forbidden-signs-explosions-arro?noredirect=1#comment385084_149747)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

These are survivor dice from the cooperative world-of-survival-horror board game Dark, Darker, Darkest.

[image: an image of the "survivor dice" expansion from dicecollector.com, with five colors of dice with the querent's symbols]

(The picture is labeled as "an expansion", but it's just a set of dice in each of the player colors. The base game uses these dice but shares a set among players.)